# How to determine UI graphic style?

Tags: gui-design, icons, graphic-design

I'm trying to determine what graphics styles and design features are being used on some recent websites.  I am not a UI developer but work with many front ends and I'm not sure how to describe certain features such as the graphics and icons to others.  So this may be more of a style question.  I'm all set with understanding and identifying the underlying technologies involved through sites such as builtwith, etc.  I've listed some examples of sites that have the styles that I'm curious about where each site has a common graphic style.

https://jawbone.com/up

https://www.quizup.com/

Comment: That is so cool how you can scroll the iPhones on that Quizup site.

Answer (score 2):

The two sites you've linked to use a flat design (very in at the moment) and are use the 'one page' idea - that is on long scrolling page. One has a sticky header navigation.

The answer is mostly related to visual style. The idea of long scrolling pages is more of a UX idea and ties into the concept that people prefer to scroll down a page than to click and jump or click and expose items.

If that doesn't provide you what you need then you might need to be more explicit.

Comment: That's definitely helpful, so thank you.  What about the icon that are used on the sites? I believe the other question that I'm trying to have answered is how were they developed?  I lack a proper descriptor but it's a very simple, clean graphic style with most icons being circular.  Is there a specific type of graphic style that is used there?  For example, look at the cloud images, circles and customer logos on this site: http://www.ampush.com/ . Hopefully that explains the second part of my question.  Thanks again for the response.

Comment: If you're talking about the tools and implementation methods then you are in the wrong place as this is about User Experience not front end development. I will say that there is a standard set of tools out there designers use as well as icons available as fonts that can be loaded with the page, but implementation questions are not part of UX.